# Can filter on a specific OU with results but not another?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that will get users based on a specific ou. The issue I'm having is that I'm able to get a list when I  enter one OU but when I try to filter it to the one I need, I get no results. I'm not getting any error when I run the script so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any advice you can provide would be grating appreciated!

Doesn't get any users but runs fine:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=Cognos Parent Folder Groups,ou=IQ User Groups,ou=IQ,ou=Administrative,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx" | select *
```

Gets users and runs fine:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=AAD,ou=Departments, ou=Administrative,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx" | select *
```

Comment: I can not see anything wrong with this code, please make sure that you can actually get an specific user from that OU by using `Get-ADUser -Identity "SAMACCOUNTNAME"` and verify the location of the retrieved object, also try `Get-ADObject -SearchBase "OU"` this should return all types of objects including contacts

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am able to get a specific user when I use Get-aduser and have been using that output to get the location. I did just try get-ADOrganizationalUnit on the extract location and it works just fine. Maybe I'm using the cmdlet. I'm very new to powershell so that it's possible.